# How do i load javascript popup only in home page? It is displayed in all page

Tags: javascript

Here is my Javascript code. How can I make it display only on the home page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: On what url you're accessing this page?

Comment: Only load this script on the homepage is one solution. Wrap it in a function which you can easily fire only on the homepage is another. There are plenty of solutions. Pick one and try. If you struggle with one solution you can ask for more assistance.

Comment: @magnudae i m quiet poor in javascript coding. Can u please suggest me some code that i can add so that i can load it only in home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this check:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if (window.location.match(/www\.infoways\.com\.np$/) || window.location.match(/www\.infoways\.com\.np\/$/)) {
        var id = '#dialog';
        // more of your code
    }
});
```

your code will be executed if url ends with `www.infoways.com.np` or `www.infoways.com.np/`

Comment: Sorry my url is www.infoways.com.np

Comment: where should i put this code. Can u please clearify a bit more.

Comment: The code didnt work. Instead the pop up is not displayed in any of the pages. Can you provide me any other solution please.

Comment: Are you sure your home page is on `http://www.infoways.com.np` and not on something like `http://www.infoways.com.np/home.html`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add conditional statement just above `var id = '#dialog';`. The steps:

1. Store your homepage url in a variable (or just write it literally like the concrete example below)
2. Compare/Check it with current url, using `location.href`

Here is the concrete example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    if (location.href !== "http://www.infoways.com.np/") {      // Add correct protocol for your url
        return;
    }

    var id = '#dialog';

    ...
```

Comment: I added the code as u have told but the popup didnt work in all pages.

Comment: change `http://www.infoways.com.np` to `http://www.infoways.com.np/`. It should work. I have updated my answers. Also note that the problem may come from another code as a result of code interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a `<script>` tag in your homepage html.